# Rigid Body Particles Falling to Outline Object (negative space typography)

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation, text-object, collision, rigidbody

[image]

I would like to use an invisible text mesh to force rigid body particles to fall around it, thereby creating the outline of the word in the negative space. I'm using larger and irregularly shaped objects as my particles (so a little trickier than the example photo, which uses rice) and so far I've been having trouble getting a clean, readable result.

I tried creating an open faced cube as a collision container for the falling particles to keep them contained to the general area, then used text converted to a mesh and extruded as collision objects inside that larger container. So far, my particles either bounce around wildly and refuse to settle, or end up landing directly on top of the word mesh and blocking parts of the letters that I am trying to reveal in the negative space.

Any suggestions from more experienced users would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: I'd check your collision stickiness.  I posted an example blend file with your similar approach but with these params tweeked.  You were close!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, I'd try to apply a Force modifier to Text that I've converted into a mesh, but alas, blender has no "Force Modifier"!

Your approach is what I'd do.  Converting the Text into a mesh, apply a clear texture (see-through) and apply Collision physics to both an underlying plane and the text mesh.   I'd adjust the Friction and Stickiness of the Text and Plane meshes to allow some particles to "remain in" the text mesh as your photo seems to indicate.  Apply some dampening to the particle physics to slow things downs a bit.   Here I didn't use as many particles as might give a better results.  I used particles mapped to an Icosphere object -- in your case you'd model a grain of rice.

[image]

And here is the [image] file example.